# Почему не применяется рамка (border) через таблицу стилей css?

Tags: html, css, html5

Таблица стилей подключена правильно, т.к. другие свойства, примененные к тексту работают. При чем рамка не применяется и к другим объектам в файле.

```
<main>
<div class = "activity"> Некоторый текст </div>
```

Код в css:

```
.activity{
    border: #070b21;
}
```

Comment: `border: 1px solid #070b21;` Например так. Либо прописывайте нужные значения отдельно для свойств border-color, border-style, border-width

Comment: иными словами, цвет рамки вполне себе применяется, но ее толщина остается равной нулю.

Comment: спасибо большое, я просто начинающий верстальщик))))

Answer (score 1):

Рамка не отображается, потому что у border есть 3 обязательных аргумента, а именно: **цвет, размер и тип** border

```css
div{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.solid{
    border: #070b21 2px solid;
}

.dashed{
  border: #070b21 2px dashed;
}

.double{
  border: #070b21 7px double;
}

.ridge{
  border: red 10px ridge;
}
```

```html
<div class = "solid"> Solid </div>
<div class = "dashed"> Dashed </div>
<div class = "double"> Double </div>
<div class = "ridge"> Ridge </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам нужно задать толщину границы и ее стиль, например так:

```
.activity{
    border: 1px solid #070b21;
}
```

Вот [тут подробнее](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border) о том, как задать рамку.